# Mongoose update query - RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am getting an **RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded** from a simple mongoose query that works perfectly in mongo native app. I am trying to update a specific element in an array from my document.

***Schema***

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    discovery: []
})
```

***Route***

```
router.post(
    '/discovery/:page',
    session.requiresLogin,
    (req, res, next) => {
        indexController.discovery(req, res)
    }
)
```

***Controller***

```
discovery: (req, res) => {
    userModel.update({
        username: req.session.username,
        'discovery.name': req.params.page
    }, {
        $set: {'discovery.$.status': true}
    }, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err
        res.status(200).send({
            status: err ? 201 : 200,
            msg: err ? 'Error' : 'Success'
        })    
    })
}
```

***Model***

```
UserSchema.statics.update = (fquery, uquery, callback) => {
    User.update(fquery, uquery, (err) => {
        if (err) return callback(err)
        callback(null)
    })
}
```

The discovery array is an object populated with `name [String]` and `status [Boolean]`

When I run this query in the native mongo app the object is updated correctly but via my node app the mongoose throws up the range error. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are wrong @NeilLunn. There is no loop, there is a ***route*** that passes the ***req and res*** object to the ***controller***, that executes the query.

Comment: Then simply show us the code all around it. The library function is used worldwide by thousands ( if not millions ) of working applications. The point of failure here is "your application", so we need to see some "context".

Comment: @NeilLunn there you go, added more code for "context"

Comment: any loop or async method executes before mongoose update query.

Comment: Why do you have a `static` method that has exactly the same method name? i.e `update()`. Do you think there just might be some recursion there? Since the `static` doesn't actually do anything ( apart from apparently causing the error ) then perhaps you should remove it. Do that and run your code again.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thank you, that worked. Novice to mongoose but that was a dumb oversight on my part.

Comment: So "ungoverned loops" and "recursion" are basically the two causes. If I were you I would stay away from defining any more static methods until you understand the purpose better. For some reason I see a lot of code like `updateShoes()` instead of simply writing `update({ "type": "shoes" }, ...` as if one was clearer than the other. But now you should know.